# capturing photo android exception when using string from resources folder

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

i am following this tutorial https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics in order to capture an image

i added the following file to xml folder

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="my_images"
    path="Android/data/mypackage/files/Pictures" />
```

The capturing of the image using the above file works perfectly as expected 
but if i used @string resource as as shown below

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="my_images"
    path="@string/mypath" />
```

```
<string name="mypath">Android/data/mypackage/files/Pictures</string>
```

i am getting the following exception

```
Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/mypackage/files/Pictures/IMG_20181018_134824_5769070663217749604.jpg
```

it workes perfectly if i don't use @string resource ,i need to use with string resources since i want to have different string when building app with gradle using build types

**EDIT**
file provider in manifest file

```
 <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@string/mypath">
        </meta-data>
    </provider>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i need to use with string resources

You cannot use string resources in arbitrary locations, such as in `FileProvider` metadata.

> i want to have different string when building app with gradle using build types

Then have different `xml` resources per build type, with different `FileProvider` metadata. IOW, replace the entire file, not a string within the file.

Comment: can u give example

Comment: how add the path to xml in string resources <string name="mypath">@xml/file_paths</string>

Comment: i added a manifestPlaceholders  in gradle like this : manifestPlaceholders = [filepath: "@xml/file_paths"] and it worked .thx